# Mathematical Conversion of Geometric Series

Tags: geometric-series

Hello I am dealing with a problem where I need to calculate the probability of a player winning a coin toss game where the two players alterantely toss a coin and the first one to toss head wins.
It states that the coin does not necessairly need to be fair. I stumbled upon this proof/solution (see below) and I understand the concept behind it but I do not understand how you get from $(I)$ to $(II)$ (I  assume: $p+q^2p+q^4p+... =p(1+q^2+q^4+...)=p(1+{1\over 1-q^2})$) how do I go from there? And how do I get from $(II)$ to $(III)$ could someone please elaborate? Thank you very much.

(SOLUTION)

So $A$ wins if head comes first time in odd number of tosses. Say $P_k$ is probability that head comes first time in $k$-th toss then $P_n=q^{n-1}\cdot p$ and
\begin{eqnarray} P &=& P_1+P_3+P_5+... \\\\
&=&p+q^2p+q^4p+q^6p+...\quad(I)\\\\
&=& {p\over 1-q^2}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad(II)\\\\
&=& {1\over 1+q}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad(III)
\end{eqnarray}

where $p$ is probability that head comes in one toss and $q=1−p$.

So if the coin is fair, then $p={1\over 2}=q$, so

$P= {2\over 3}$

(/SOLUTION)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267809/probability-of-winning-draw-game/4267820#4267820). It is essentially the same problem. You don't need to use a series.

Comment: Thank you, although I would still really like to know how to convert the line (I) into line (II) :).

Comment: After you've factored out the $p$ you get the standard geometric series $1+q+q^2+...$. This is a standard result that is easy to prove with partial sums. You should be able to google for "solution to geometric series" and find many examples of how to do this.

Comment: $\frac{p}{1-q^2}=\frac{p}{(1-q)(1+q)}=\frac{1}{1+q}$.